# How to validate if user exists without Optional in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have SpringBoot application where user can register using email and username. I can validate if email already exists in database properly with Optional using isPresent() method but I can't do the same with username because of UserDetailsService in UserDetailsServiceImpl.java I'm using in my project which I need.

When I Have in `AppUserRepo.java`

```
AppUser findByUsername(String username);
Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email);
```

instead of

```
Optional<AppUser> findByUsername(String username);
```

everything works, but I can't validate if username already exists.
When I have

```
Optional<AppUser> findByUsername(String username);
```

I get errors and it says I have to change `Optional<AppUser>` To `AppUser`.
 How Can I solve this problem?

My repository of AppUser - AppUserRepo.java

```
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface AppUserRepo extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {

    AppUser findByUsername(String username);
    Optional<AppUser> findByEmail(String email);

}
```

When I want to use `Optional<AppUser> findByUsername(String username);` I get errors in my UserService.java

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private TokenRepo tokenRepo;
    private MailService mailService;
    private AppUserRepo appUserRepo;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(AppUserRepo appUserRepo, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, TokenRepo tokenRepo, MailService mailService) {
        this.appUserRepo = appUserRepo;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.tokenRepo = tokenRepo;
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }

    public void addUser(AppUser appUser) {
        appUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(appUser.getPassword()));
        appUser.setRole("ROLE_USER");
        appUserRepo.save(appUser);
        sendToken(appUser);
    }

    private void sendToken(AppUser appUser) {
        String tokenValue = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Token token = new Token();
        token.setValue(tokenValue);
        token.setAppUser(appUser);
        tokenRepo.save(token);
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/token?value=" + tokenValue;

        try {
            mailService.sendMail(appUser.getEmail(), "Register", url, false);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public Optional <AppUser> findByEmail(String email) {
        return appUserRepo.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Optional <AppUser> findByUsername(String username) {
        return appUserRepo.findByEmail(username);
    }

    public boolean appUserEmailExists(String email){
        return findByEmail(email).isPresent();
    }

    public boolean appUserUsernameExists(String username){
        return findByUsername(username).isPresent();
    }
}
```

It tells that I need to change from `Optional<AppUser>` to `AppUser` in my AppUserRepo.java

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {


    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(@ModelAttribute AppUser appUser, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("appUser", new AppUser());
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerOk(@Valid @ModelAttribute("appUser") AppUser appUser, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

//        if (userService.appUserUsernameExists(appUser.getUsername())) {
//            bindingResult.addError(new FieldError
//                    ("appUser", "username", "Login already exists"));
//        }

        if (userService.appUserEmailExists(appUser.getEmail())) {
            bindingResult.addError(new FieldError
                    ("appUser", "email", "Email already exists"));
        }

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "register";
        } else {
            userService.addUser(appUser);
            return "redirect:register?success";
        }
    }
}
```

Class below implements UserDetailsService I have problem with.
UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private AppUserRepo appUserRepo;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(AppUserRepo appUserRepo) {
        this.appUserRepo = appUserRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String user) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return appUserRepo.findByUsername(user);
    }
}
```

AppUser.java

```
@Data
@Entity
public class AppUser implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 4, message = "Atleast 4 characters")
    private String username;

    @Size(min = 6, message = "Atleast 6 characters")
    private String password;

    private String role;

    @Column(name = "Email")
    @NotBlank
    @Email(message = "real e-mail adress required")
    private String email;

    @Pattern(regexp = "\\d{9}")
    private String phone;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String surname;

    private boolean isEnabled;

    public AppUser() {
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your `AppUser` class content

Comment: Done - Sorry, I forgot.

Comment: What’s wrong with `AppUser findByUsername(String username);` and `repo.findByUsername("...") != null`?

Comment: Wow haha, thank you so much, everything works great! Really I thank you so much. This was really that simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
AppUser findByUsername(String username);
```

and

```
if (myrepo.findByUsername("...") != null)
```